# Proof regarding cardinality and cartesian product.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

**Let A be a set with the property that |A×A|=|A|.  Prove that |A^n|=|A| for any n∈N.  Here A^n is the n-fold Cartesian product of A.**

I am trying to solve this example for my introductory proof class and am having a hard time figuring out what to do. I believe that because |A×A|=|A|, there exists a bijective function (f) such that f: A×A -> A.

And since we want to prove that |A^n|=|A|, we have to show that there exists a bijective function (h) such that h: A^n -> A.

Is this correct? And if so am I on the right track?
Any guidance,explanation, or answer would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Prove it by induction on $n$; use the fact that $A^{n+1}=A^n\times A$.

Comment: Have you covered proof by induction yet?

Comment: I opened the post to comment the same, @BrianM.Scott. Instead, I upvoted your comment.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Makes so much more sense, I didn't even think to use induction. Thank you

Comment: @Artek: You’re welcome.